# Do polymer banknotes generally contain animal fat?

Tags: cash, paper-money

There is currently [a brouhaha in England about the new polymer £5 notes](http://money.aol.co.uk/2016/11/29/why-is-there-animal-fat-in-the-new-5-note/), which [contain trace amounts of animal fat](https://twitter.com/bankofengland/status/803273440807550976?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw).

Is this problem unique to England, or is it common to other places that use [polymer banknotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_banknote)?

Comment: I have no idea if this is on topic here, or if it would be better at [chemistry.se]?  But, interesting question anyway.

Comment: I could see it being on topic, sort of...if I stretch my neck and squint really hard. If I have an objection to the use of animals in products, I may want to avoid them. In the world of Personal Finance, which currencies or specific note denominations should I avoid? Could also port to http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance and money.

Comment: @Victor For some people, this question is basically equivalent to "should I stop using cash?" I believe it is on topic for Personal Finance and Money.

Comment: In my opinion, any question about the physical currency that people use everyday in their financial lives is on-topic here.

Comment: @200_success - If you asked the question "should I stop using cash?" I would recommend that it be closed too, as this would be based on opinion. Your title reads: "Do polymer banknotes generally contain animal fat?" You then answer this yourself in the first line of your question? If this offends you then don't use them - that is up to you, most payments these days are done electronically anyway.

Comment: @Victor Just to be clear, the question in the title is not answered in the first sentence, as the question is about polymer banknotes from all countries in general, and the first sentence is discussing the current situation in England only.

Comment: @BenMiller - who cares, why would there be any problems in using a currency with trace amounts of animal fat, even to vegetarians and vegans, you are not eating the notes are you? Nothing to do with investing or personal finance.

Comment: Not up to us to say whether someone else's concerns are valid or not.

Comment: @Ben Miller: I think it is answered.  Other currencies may use animal fats (or not), but it seems that only in England is it a problem, and then only among a small - but very vocal - minority.

Comment: @Victor some of the vegetarians and vegans I now refuse to own anything that contains animal products; they wear faux leather shoes, chain or plastic belts etc. so it doesn't matter whether they are eating it at all. Even a trace amount on an item is so fundamentally against their ethicsthat they refuse to own it. This is a vlaid question.

Comment: ugh didn't notice my necromancy having been away for a while, sorry all.

Answer (score 5):

Polypropylene, the base polymer typically used in the production of polymer banknotes (see the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_banknote) for example) often (but not always) contains trace amounts of tallow-derived stearates.  While it is possible to produce them without these animal-derived additives, it is not as inexpensive (or is simply not something manufacturers pay much attention to).

There are some efforts to produce non-animal-containing plastics, such as the [Kosher plastics movement](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1165/the-story-behind-kosher-plastics/), and other use cases such as in the case of pharmaceutical equipment it can be advantageous to use [animal-free plastic equipment](https://www.nordsonmedical.com/newsletter/animal-free.htm) due to the paperwork around anything that could be a potential BSE vector (Bovine Spongiform Encephalitis, commonly known as 'mad cow disease').

I can't find much definitive on notes from other countries, just speculation like [this article about Canada](http://www.straight.com/blogra/836621/homeless-vancouver-beef-fat-new-british-ps5-note-likely-also-canadian-polymer-bills) which speculates it is likely but does not state any definitive evidence.   This will likely change as this story breaks (and other countries are asked the same question as BoE was).

Bank of Scotland has now [confirmed their notes do *not* contain tallow or animal products](http://www.scottishfinancialnews.com/11090/scottish-banks-promise-their-notes-are-vegan/), so UK vegans have an animal-free option for their 5 pound notes.

Answer (score 3):

According to [CNN Money](http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/29/news/pound-animal-fat-money-in-notes-bills/), the company that supplies polymer to the UK for use in currency is Innovia Films.  The company also provides polymer to 23 other countries for use in polymer currency, including Australia, Canada, and Mexico.

The article quotes spokesperson Patricia Potts, who claims that animal ingredients are against company policy and that the tallow was added by an unnamed supplier.

According to [this report on ABC News (Australia)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-11-30/anger-over-animal-fat-used-in-britian's-new-polymer-currency/8077676), another Innovia spokesperson, Carlos Fernandez, confirmed that "miniscule amounts" of tallow are also used in the production of Australian banknotes.